# IDAstar on pancake sorting problem, how many node expansions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I am attempting to implement IDAstar and so just need to double check my reasoning. 
Suppose I am trying to solve the following pancake sorting problem using IDA-star assuming all operations have a cost of 1 and assuming that I am using the zero-heuristic:

```
start state= 1 0 2 3 4 5 
goal state= 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

I believe that it would take 2 node expansions to solve this problem instance using IDAstar as follows:

First sweep with a threshold of zero would expand the start state. 
Second sweep with a threshold of 1 would expand the start state again and this is when we discover the goal state.

is this correct?